# Libraries for making a voice chat application

Tags: c++, open-source, chat, voip

My development team is going to build a voice chat application.

Our plan is to use a pre-made library just for this purpose, but we haven't found any good one after days of searching the internet, so I thought I would consider a question here!

**So the question is:**
What library / project do you recommend? We are deadly serious with this, so it needs to be a good working one. Preferable an open-source one as well.

We have been looking at some **XMPP** libraries and projects, but none seems to be up-to-date, tested and well-documented.

Comment: Oh, I'm looking at the source right now, but can't find anything that is about voice communication. Second, there's no documentation for it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at [`libjingle`](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) ? Its the base library for `Google Talk`.

Comment: libjingle has the disadvantage of not being XMPP compliant, or not following any other open standards as far as I know. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Its defined as extensions to XMPP, see http://code.google.com/apis/talk/jep_extensions/extensions.html

Comment: Yes we looked at libjingle and have been trying to use it for a while, but it's really bad documented and a bit bugged, and the examples provided doesn't really work. But we are keeping it as an alternative if we don't find any 'better'

Answer (score 0):

And on what platforms are you interested in such libraies ? I would recommend http://camaya.net/gloox/ or http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/ for portability, completeness and open standards.

Comment: Yes, we have considered them. But after checking the fetatures of each library, neither of them seems to feature the 'Jingle' extension (XEP-0166) which enables voice chat. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh yes platforms; the client is to be run under Windows, and the server under Linux.

Comment: isn't http://camaya.net/api/gloox-trunk/namespacegloox_1_1Jingle.html and https://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/smack/tags/smack_3_1_0_beta1/jingle/extension/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/jingle/JingleManager.java what you are asking for ?

Comment: Oh, after some research in the changelog of smack, they seems to be supporting Jingle.. But gloox on the other hand; quoted from their doc: "Beware! The classes in the Jingle namespace implement the signaling part of Jingle only. At this point, there is no support for actually establishing any connection to a remote entity, nor for transfering any media in any way whatsoever."

Answer (score 0):

www.pjsip.org
I think it is the best sip sdk around.